# how to control process bar in bootstrap fileinput plugin?

Tags: jquery

I am using a file input plugin located here: http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input

Is there a way to control the percentage of the progress bar? The layout is :

```
progress: '<div class="progress">\n' +
    '    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped text-center" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{percent}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{percent}%;">\n' +
    '        {percent}%\n' +
    '     </div>\n' +
    '</div>',
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might need to be more specific as to what you mean by control it.

Comment: @AndrewBone I would like to set up percentages. As soon as filelock event is triggered, the process bar hits 100%. However, my process still continues for about 30-45 more seconds. I would like to set an ajax method and increase the percentage X amounts as things are done on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know if this will work, I think it should but I'm not certain.

```
progress: '<div class="progress">\n' +
    '    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped text-center" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="'+{percent}-offsetVariable+'" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:calc(({percent}-'+offsetVariable+')%);">\n' +
    '        '+{percent}-offsetVariable+'%\n' +
    '     </div>\n' +
    '</div>',
```

Then you'd need to define your offsetVariable some where, and have it tick down when the time is right.